# Trying to set border of an element to white to hide border of another element

Tags: html, css, border

I'm using Styled Components with React to build a feature that allows the user to select a tab along the left-hand side which expands content on the right, like so:

[image]

I'm trying to set a `border-right: 1px solid white` on my `StyledHeadingTab` (along the left when active) to override the border that wraps my `StyledPanel` on the right (so that the heading "flows" into the panel"

```
const StyledPanel = styled.div`
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-left: 64px;
  padding-right: 64px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  width: 954px;
`;

const StyledHeadingTab = styled.div`
  max-height: 72px;
  width: 294px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
`;
```

I've tried using relative positioning and z-index to no effect.

Comment: I've got a feeling it's because the border you're trying to make white is a part of the main content box not the menu box. That of course means changing `border-left` on that box but the entire height of it would go white and that wouldn't work properly either. Is it more easily achieveable if you remove the borders altogether and create edges using `box-shadow` intsead?

Comment: thanks Rob, but wouldn't using `box-shadow` just loop us back round with the same issue, because I need the border/shadow to be all around except for the small area where the heading-tab meets the panel?

Comment: This doc doesn't exactly address it but it does talk about masking borders. Perhaps a plain white image would work with this exact technique? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-border

Comment: I'll take another look at this - although I don't think I could specify jus the `right` border with mask-border. Possibly need to re-think my implementation of this!